# Recover overwritten file in dropbox

Tags: dropbox

I had an old txt file in my dropbox, then I was making a new one and saving, and by accident used the old files name (So its overwritten).

If I go to the Recover previous version then the old version is not there, neither is in the deleted folder.

How do I recover it?

Comment: dropbox only has 30 day recovery in the free version. Another thing, maybe your OS did delete/create instead of overwrite. Take a look at https://www.dropbox.com/events to see what happened

Comment: Yes they only have 30 day recovery, but that should mean I had 30 days to undo my overwritten file, not 30 days from the day I created the initial file. I could also accept if the overwritten file was put in "deleted items" but that didnt happen either

Comment: no it does not. I just tested it with an old file. Obviously you can only see all versions within the last 30 days.

Comment: And if that is not a bug then I will have to find another provider

Comment: It is not a bug.  Dropbox does not keep multiple versions, of the same file to my knowledge, not even if you pay.

Comment: @Ramhound your knowledge is wrong. If you want to try: create a file, wait for dropbox to sync, edit it, wait for sync, edit again, wait for sync. Now, on the website you can right-click on the file and select "previous versions". It also works for shared folders (which is nice, because there is always this one user who changes files unintentionally)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to recover a deleted folder or file? You said you overwrote a text file which is easily recoverable if you have still have the folder. If you deleted the folder later, you need to restore the folder first. Once the folder is restored, the file within if there are previous versions (within your time limit), can be restored to previous version.

Dropbox is actually not very good about restoring folders as a point in time restore. If you have Windows, using System Protection and Windows Backup is actually the best way to recover entire folders and files for a specific point in time.

[image]